# Faster Bitmap Rescale

Tags: c++, image, algorithm

I wrote a small function to rescale a image to a specific size without cropping it (by adding black borders to fit it) and it works, yet it is slow specially on high resolutions. Please take a look and tell me how can I increase the efficiency of the function. Or if there s a better code that I can use to achieve the same result.

```
static int ReScale(char* srcBuffer, int srcLen, int srcStart, int srcStride, int srcHeight, VideoInfo::ePixelFormat srcPixelFormat,
                   char* dstBuffer, int dstLen, int dstStart, int dstStride, int dstHeight, VideoInfo::ePixelFormat dstPixelFormat, bool reverseCopy)
{
    int srcPixelDepth = VideoInfo::GetPixelFormatSize(srcPixelFormat);
    int srcWidth = static_cast<int>(floor(srcStride / static_cast<float>(srcPixelDepth)));
    int dstPixelDepth = VideoInfo::GetPixelFormatSize(dstPixelFormat);
    int dstWidth = static_cast<int>(floor(dstStride / static_cast<float>(dstPixelDepth)));

    float resizeRatio = min(dstWidth / static_cast<float>(srcWidth), dstHeight / static_cast<float>(srcHeight));
    int dstXOffset = static_cast<int>((dstWidth - (resizeRatio * srcWidth)) / 2.f);
    int dstYOffset = static_cast<int>((dstHeight - (resizeRatio * srcHeight)) / 2.f);
    ZeroMemory(dstBuffer + dstStart, dstLen);

    srcBuffer += srcStart;
    dstBuffer += dstStart;

    dstWidth -= 2 * dstXOffset;
    dstHeight -= 2 * dstYOffset;

    int dstPixelOffset = 0;
    int srcPixelOffset = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < dstHeight; y++)
    {
        dstPixelOffset = dstXOffset * dstPixelDepth + (y + dstYOffset) * dstStride;
        for (int x = 0; x < dstWidth; x++)
        {
            srcPixelOffset = static_cast<int>(min(y / resizeRatio, srcHeight));
            if (reverseCopy)
            {
                srcPixelOffset = srcHeight - (srcPixelOffset + 1);
            }
            srcPixelOffset = static_cast<int>(min(x / resizeRatio, srcWidth)) * srcPixelDepth + srcPixelOffset * srcStride;
            if (srcPixelOffset + srcPixelDepth < srcLen && dstPixelOffset + dstPixelDepth < dstLen)
            {
                memcpy(dstBuffer + dstPixelOffset, srcBuffer + srcPixelOffset, srcPixelDepth);
            }
            dstPixelOffset += dstPixelDepth;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Options *:

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
/Studio 12.0\VC\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
/Studio 12.0\VC\PlatformSDK\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
/Kits\8.1\include" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D 
/"WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D 
/"_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gz /Oy-/MD 
/Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\*****.pch"
```

Profiling Result *:
[image: Profiling Result]

Comment: Can you add what compiler options you are currently using? No point optimizing code when the compiler can do it for you.

Comment: There are too many division operations - usually it is slow. Try to replace all `/ resizeRatio` by `* resizeCoef` (and add after declaration of `resizeRatio` line `const float resizeCoef = 1.0 / resizeRatio`).

Comment: And you should do a quick profile if you can to determine your bottleneck. If your images are very large, you could also be limited by memory bandwidth.

Comment: Any modern compiler will do micro-optimizations like these (multiplication vs division) for you as long as you not actively preventing it and compiling  with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @TheDark, Compiler options added to the post.

Comment: @Tafuri, Profiling result added to the post. Not very large, source and destination both can be up to 2MP, Full HD. And I don't think that memory limited me because I have high CPU usage.

Comment: You are doing simple linear scaling here, not e.g. bicubic which would require floating point calculations. Thus replace the floating point arithmetic by integer arithmetic. E.g. `srcX = (dstX*srcWidth)/dstWidth`. Even better would be to use a library like OpenCV.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati what profiler are you using?

Comment: @Ulterior, VS Profiler for CPU sampling

Comment: You can use floating-point arithmetic, but don't recalculate every pixel position from scratch. For both source and destination you have constant (fractional) pixel strides, which you can just add in each iteration.

Comment: The implementation also requires `srcPixelDepth == dstPixelDepth`, no?

Comment: @MOehm, For now it does. I see your point. I should test it out.

Comment: Have you tried enabling SSE code generation in VS? (/arch:SSE2) This can usually give you a nice performance boost.
You could also potentially gain some performance by refactoring out the if statements from within the for-loop, (for example by using different for loops), this would allow the compiler to optimize the code further.

Comment: As @MOehm suggested, you don't need to perform per-pixel divisions (either FP or integer) at all.  After O(1) divisions at the start, you can use Bresenham's algorithm to step through "source pixels" using only integer additions and comparisons.  (In a description of Bresenham's algorithm for drawing a line that is wider than it is tall, just replace "Y co-ord" with "source X co-ord".)

Comment: @j_random_hacker I tried to merge two ideas with calculating the first pixel of each row and then moving forward by addition.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati: You're still using FP arithmetic in that innermost loop.  This can be eliminated by using Bresenham's algorithm.  I certainly expect that avoiding per-pixel integer<->FP conversions will give a big speedup.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati: On closer inspection, I see that that multiplication is for skipping over blocks of bytes corresponding to individual pixels, so maybe it needs to stay.  The FP<->integer conversions can still be eliminated, however.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, How can I eliminate the FP-Int conversion from the inner loop?

Comment: @SoroushFalahati: The fact that you're asking this question means *you haven't googled Bresenham's algorithm yet*.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I read it, at least I read the wiki page about it. Yet I don see any fp conversion to Int in my inner loop that can be refactored. I mean even the Bresenham's algorithm has at least one fp to int conversion. (y1-y0)/(x1-x0) is fp isn't it? And I have the srcPixelXStride. Also I am talking about the second post. below one. Not the original question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Algorithm_for_integer_arithmetic

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I see now. At least I managed to apply it on Up-scaling. I still trying to understand it to make down-scaling works as expected. Problem is here that based on Wiki's version of algorithm, line can only goes to right-down which is fine for up-scaling but not for down-scaling.

Comment: You need to take uniform-size steps in the *longest* of the two "directions".  So if you're downscaling, you should step through each pixel in the source image, and use Bresenham to determine when to move to the next screen pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored the function to apply your suggestions and enabled the SSE2 and fp:fast options. Performance increased by 3x:

```
static int ReScale(char* srcBuffer, int srcLen, int srcStart, int srcStride, int srcHeight, VideoInfo::ePixelFormat srcPixelFormat,
                   char* dstBuffer, int dstLen, int dstStart, int dstStride, int dstHeight, VideoInfo::ePixelFormat dstPixelFormat, bool reverseCopy)
{
    int srcPixelDepth = VideoInfo::GetPixelFormatSize(srcPixelFormat);
    int srcWidth = static_cast<int>(floor(srcStride / static_cast<float>(srcPixelDepth)));
    int dstPixelDepth = VideoInfo::GetPixelFormatSize(dstPixelFormat);
    int dstWidth = static_cast<int>(floor(dstStride / static_cast<float>(dstPixelDepth)));

    float resizeRatio = min(dstWidth / static_cast<float>(srcWidth), dstHeight / static_cast<float>(srcHeight));
    int dstXOffset = static_cast<int>((dstWidth - (resizeRatio * srcWidth)) / 2.f);
    int dstYOffset = static_cast<int>((dstHeight - (resizeRatio * srcHeight)) / 2.f);
    ZeroMemory(dstBuffer + dstStart, dstLen);

    srcBuffer += srcStart;
    dstBuffer += dstStart;

    dstWidth -= 2 * dstXOffset;
    dstHeight -= 2 * dstYOffset;

    int dstPixelOffset = 0;
    int srcPixelOffset = 0;
    int srcPixelYOffset = 0;
    float srcPixelXOffset = 0;
    float srcPixelXStride = 1 / resizeRatio;
    int pixelDepthSize = min(srcPixelDepth, dstPixelDepth);
    for (int y = 0; y < dstHeight; y++)
    {
        dstPixelOffset = dstXOffset * dstPixelDepth + (y + dstYOffset) * dstStride;
        srcPixelYOffset = static_cast<int>(min(y / resizeRatio, srcHeight));
        srcPixelYOffset = (reverseCopy ? (srcHeight - (srcPixelYOffset + 1)) : srcPixelYOffset) * srcStride;
        srcPixelXOffset = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < dstWidth; x++)
        {
            srcPixelOffset = srcPixelYOffset + (static_cast<int>(min(srcPixelXOffset, srcWidth)) * srcPixelDepth);
            if (srcPixelOffset + pixelDepthSize < srcLen && dstPixelOffset + pixelDepthSize < dstLen)
            {
                memcpy(dstBuffer + dstPixelOffset, srcBuffer + srcPixelOffset, pixelDepthSize);
            }
            dstPixelOffset += dstPixelDepth;
            srcPixelXOffset += srcPixelXStride;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Special thanks to @MOehm, @Tafuri and other commenters

Comment: I wonder what was the effect of SSE2 and fp:fast options. I mean: "what is the performance gain without these options?"

Comment: @simurg, I removed the profiling results, but I remember it was like 5-4% CPU usage to 4-3% so about 20%.

Comment: I believe it is better to measure the time it takes to complete the task, but I guess you might not isolate this function from the rest of your code.

Comment: @simurg, yeah, I should have said that this performance gain may not be directly from this function but from the other parts of the project as well; as I didnt isolated the function nor tried to take benchmarks.